# Am I required to report accident to my personal auto insurer if I was driving a government vehicle

Tags: car-insurance, automotive

I have a squeaky clean driving record for the last 20 years (since I started driving). Last month, I was in an accident for the first time. It was a minor fender bender. I was on official government duty when it happened and was driving a federal government vehicle. The government is self insured and will cover all liability claims on my behalf.

I was issued a citation by the state police which I promptly paid off.

Am I required to report this accident to my personal auto insurance? Specifically, does the law require it? What happens if I do report it and what if I don't? It's needless to say here, but no claims will be filed against my personal insurance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to report it to the responsible insurer or self-insurance claim processing firm so they can process the claim.

You only need to report to citation and/or accident to your personal insurer if asked. Some insurers will ask every once and a while in a renewal application. Some won't. Many insurers have a service that notes citations even if you don't report them. If you change insurers, the new insurer will ask in your application for insurance.

Comment: The other party involved in the accident has been given all the information on how to file a claim with the government. It appears that my insurance will find out one way or another. Some points will show up on my driver's record and they will ask during renewal in a few months. Thanks.

Comment: @cryptic0 In the case of private insurance, it is generally better for the insurance company to hear from its insured first (and not doing so risks your insurance coverage). The analysis might not be as strong with federal self-insurance, but the basic idea is to get an insurance defense lawyer on the case ASAP to prevent you from doing something that makes the claim worse (like no preserving key evidence).